# Maven release plugin - Non-parseable settings error

Tags: linux, maven, maven-release-plugin

I have a big maven project I want to release using the `mvn release` plugin. I can run the `mvn release:prepare` locally (on an `OS X` computer), however when I try the same on my `GNU/Linux` build agent (Which is a `Centos 7.4`), I get the following problem:

```
[INFO] Executing goals 'clean verify'...
[INFO] [ERROR] Error executing Maven.
[INFO] [ERROR] 1 problem was encountered while building the effective settings
[INFO] [FATAL] Non-parseable settings /tmp/release-settings6955073192509771699.xml: start tag unexpected character " (position: TEXT seen ...<properties>\n        <os.detected.release.like."... @21:36)  @ /tmp/release-settings6955073192509771699.xml, line 21, column 36
```

I have tried to find any reference similar to `<os.detected.release.like."` in the pom files, yet I've been unlucky since it is not present anywhere. I have also tried to read that `/tmp/release-settings6955073192509771699.xml` file, which does not exist. (Possibly generated and deleted by maven during this phase)

To make this even more strange, another coworker is able to run `mvn release:prepare` on his `Windows` workstation and also in the `Ubuntu bash` embedded there (Which is a `Ubuntu GNU/Linux` with `kernel 3.4`)

I am currently completely puzzled, any idea where should I look for the error origin here? I guess is in the parent `pom.xml`, but it just looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the sub-modules in the project was using `kr.motd.maven` on version `1.3.0`, it seems that there is a bug in this version not allowing the release on `Centos 7.4` (Working however on `Ubuntu`, `OS X` and `Windows 10`).

Upgrading the plugin version to `1.5.0` (latest) fixed the problem for me.

It is quite strange that the project can be in fact built with the `1.3.0` on `Centos 7.4`, it is only failing during `mvn release:prepare` phase.